# what technology should i used to build an window app run with cloud services

Tags: wpf, database, silverlight, cloud

I have a software requirement like that:
An app run on window but this app can connect to server to get and use its file by user.

User A can **Log in**, **View all** *his file* **from server, Create new file, Edit content, Upload, Share file, View share file of another user**.

I usually use .Net framework.

So what technology should i used to resolve this requirement

I really need some advice helpful

Thank!!!

Comment: Which windows you want to build for

Comment: is it an internet or intranet application? Any chances that it should be available on a mobile device in the future?

Comment: hi CognitiveDesire, at the moment is window7 but the future i will upgrade it for window8

Comment: Hi KyorCode, it's desktop application however i want to build one version for smart phone in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon the comments, I would advice to go for a clean separation between your UI and application functionality.

This will allow  you to build possible multiple interfaces ( Win8, Mobile, ... ) for the same application. For Windows environment and you are used to .NET I suggest you take a look at WPF ( Windows Presentation Foundation ). I'm sure you will find that some people already created pretty solid file managers in WPF. It could serve as a good base for yours.

Few pointers if you look at WPF, look on http://www.codeplex.com for frameworks that could ease your coding. ([Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/), [PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/), ... ). A very popular pattern is [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), this will structure your code so you can easy adjust it in the future.

Further more I think you can get very far with the windows build in libraries to manage the files.

For the editing you'll find a nice challenge to do that in the application, the easy road would just be to let the user open the file from the application into it's proper environment ( e.g.: a word document in Word, excel document in excel, etc.. ).

To get sharing going, multiple options are available. I'm think of sending email links, in application notifications, etc... Sharing could also mean that you set certain permissions on those files. For this you could take it to the limit of domain security management ( talking to an active directory to get the proper permissions etc. ) or you could simple implement your own into your application and restricting it on that level.

Comment: Thank you for your suggest, I intend use WPF to build the app too.

Comment: My app need allow user drawing some thing, save result to their file by xml file. So when editing, user use my app to edit their file

Comment: my problem is that, if the app only run offline on window, it's ok. But with the requirement that user can share their file to another people to view content when they want, and they can down load their own file from internet to edit it. I wonder the way to structure system to resolve this idea